# pass extra paprameter with serialized form in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-post

In the following example am submitting a serialized form using post method. Its working fine now. But I want to pass some more extra parameter to the submitted page. How to pass that value to the form. I dont like the way to keep that value in a hidden field in that form. Is there any other way to do this?

```
var postUrl = 'myphppage.php';

$.post(postUrl,
    $('#myForm').serialize(),
    function(response) {    

        if(response.status){
        //do something
        }else{
        }

    },'json'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add simply like how you do string concatenation. For eg., you wanna add a parameter, `username` with the value `praveen`, you can do this way:

```
$.post(postUrl,
    $('#myForm').serialize() + '&username=praveen',
    function(response) {    
        if(response.status){
            //do something
        }else{

        }
    },'json'
);
```

But just make sure you URLEncode the values and keys.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
var postUrl = 'myphppage.php?q='+variable
```

and use `$_GET['q']` to receive the value

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is:

```
$.post(postUrl, { form: $('#myForm').serialize(), others: 'Ramiz' }, function(response) {    
    if(response.status){
            //do something
    } else{
            //do something else
    }

  },'json'
);
```

You can also use hidden fields in form then you won't need anything just serialize the form object and you will have them in it:

`<input type="hidden" name="others" id="others" value="Ramiz" />`
`<input type="hidden" name="others" id="another" value="Arun" />`

Comment: how do you access the appended value on the receiving end(in the server side) ?